# Terraform dynamic variable

Tags: terraform

I'm creating subnets as part of a seperate terraform template and exporting the IDs as follows.

```
output "subnet-aza-dev" {
  value = "${aws_subnet.subnet-aza-dev.id}"
}
output "subnet-azb-dev" {
  value = "${aws_subnet.subnet-azb-dev.id}"
}
output "subnet-aza-test" {
  value = "${aws_subnet.subnet-aza-test.id}"
}
output "subnet-azb-test" {
  value = "${aws_subnet.subnet-azb-test.id}"
}
...
```

I'm then intending to lookup these IDs in another template which is reused to provision multiple environments. Example below shows my second template is calling a module to provision an EC2 instance and is passing through the subnet_id.

```
variable "environment" {
    description = "Environment name"
    default     = "dev"
}

module "sql-1-ec2" {
  source     = "../modules/ec2winserver_sql"
  ...
  subnet_id  = "${data.terraform_remote_state.env-shared.subnet-aza-dev}" 
}
```

What I'd like to do is pass the environment variable as part of the lookup for the subnet_id e.g.

```
subnet_id  = "${data.terraform_remote_state.env-shared.subnet-aza-${var.environment}"
```

However I'm aware that variable interpolation isn't supported. I've tried using a map inside of the first terraform template to export them all to a 'subnet' which I could then use to lookup from the second template. This didn't work as I was unable to output variables inside of the map.

This sort of design pattern is something I've used previously with CloudFormation, however I'm much newer to terraform. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Have you tried without wrapping `var.environment` in `${}`? Unsure if you'll be able to do what you want, but with interpolation, you only need it once - and it's already inside that parent `"${}"`

Comment: @TJBiddle unfortunately when I specify it as `subnet_id  = "${data.terraform_remote_state.env-shared.subnet-aza-var.environment}" ` it doesn't expand the variable and instead it tries to read a `subnet-aza-var.environment` attribute which doesn't exist in the env-shared resource

Answer (score 0):

Worked out a way to do this using data sources

```
variable "environment" {
    description = "Environment name"
    default     = "dev"
}

module "sql-1-ec2" {
  source     = "../modules/ec2winserver_sql"
  ...
  subnet_id  = "${data.aws_subnet.subnet-aza.id}" 
}

data "aws_subnet" "subnet-aza" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["${var.product}-${var.environment}-${var.environmentno}-subnet-aza"]
  }
}
data "aws_subnet" "subnet-azb" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["${var.product}-${var.environment}-${var.environmentno}-subnet-azb"]
  }
}
```

Whilst this works and fulfils my original need, I'd like to improve on this by moving the `data` blocks to within the module, so that there's less repetition. Still working on that one though...